# Nearest returning s different length of output with same input data

Tags: functions, cluster-analysis

I am trying to classify a list of 2D data points into different clusters based on the Euclidean distance between the points and the clusters' centroids, i.e. the point will be classify into the cluster in which it has the nearest distance with. The function will then expect to output the number of data points contained in each cluster.

```
testing[pts_, k_] := 
  Module[{centroid, classi, countnew},  
  (*randomly initialize clusteer centroids*)
  centroid = RandomChoice[pts, k];  
  (*calculate distance of the points from each cluster centroid*)
  (*classify each point to the nearest centroid cluster *)
  classi = Flatten@Nearest[centroid -> Range[Length@centroid], pts];
  Print["Length@classi ", Length @ classi];
  (*number of points in each cluster*)
  countnew = Map[Count[classi, #] &, Range[k]];]
```

I then tested this function on a data set with 488892 data points. However, when I tried to trace the function, I realised `Nearest` didn't output the same length as my input data

```
Length @ imgdata
```

> `488892`

```
testing[imgdata, 10]
```

> `Length@classi 488927`

I would expect the printed value labeled `Length @ classi` to give me the same value as `Length @ imgdata`. I really have no idea why I don't. The most bizarre thing is that every time I ran the function with the same input data, I get different output lengths:

```
testing[imgdata, 10]
```

> `Length@classi 488906`

```
testing[imgdata, 10]
```

> `Length@classi 488940`

Is this a bug or I missed something in my code?

Comment: I don't suppose you could share your "imgdata" via pastebin or similar, would be helpful, thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `imgdata` has no duplicate values?

Comment: could you try using "First/@" instead of "Flatten@", I think the issue is when there are effective ties in distance between points, Nearest returns the list of equidistant points {p0,p1,p2} (for example) instead of a single point {p0}, and "Flatten@" indiscriminately adds all 3 to the list instead of just the single point

Comment: You missed supplying a complete examples. Presumably the (missing) input data is comprised of integers and there are a handful of ties where `Nearest` returns two elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nearest is not guaranteed to return just a single point

```
points = Join[Range[5], Range[5]]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} *)

Nearest[points,3]
(* {3,3} *)
```

in your code above, please use "First/@" instead of "Flatten@" to get the list "classi" that you expect

Comment: That's exactly what happened! Thank you!

Comment: And `RandomChoice` can also return duplicate values. Use `RandomSample` instead.